# Unable to access/use JFrog Pipelines

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cicd, jfrog-cli, jfrog-pipelines

I'm using Jenkins for CI/CD. Now I need to use JFrog Pipelines for some reasons. So I took a Trail account to explore the JFrog Pipelines and I'm unable to use Pipelines.
It is showing "Activate". But when I click on it is showing error "undefined TypeError:cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')". I can't find any help online or in youtube. Please help!

Tried checking, if there are restrictions or permissions that need to be configured in order to use JFrog pipelines. but no luck